# Web Scraping Python: Div classes have different values. How to overcome the situation?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from World Bank (https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/leadership/managers).

Requirement is to scrape the Names, Designation, Images, Biography of each manager.

I have successfully scraped the above data. But when trying to scrape the bio, by redirecting to the individual manager's page, the div class' names and it's structure is not same.

How can I overcome this situation?

Code snippet used:

```
def get_person_profile(url):
 
    person_content = requests.get(url).content
    
    person_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(person_content,'html.parser')
    
    div_data = person_soup.find('div',class_='redesign_text_collapse_expand parbase section')
    
    profile_data = div_data.findAll('p')
    
    profile_text = []
    
    for i in profile_data:
        profile_text.append(i.text)
    
    return_profile = '\n'.join(profile_text)
    
    return return_profile
```

In the above code `'redesign_text_collapse_expand parbase section'` is used. This is not uniform across links (managers links).

(Please refer below two links:

https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/people/antonella-bassani

https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/people/c/christopher-h-stephens )

Also, I can't scrape using only `<p>` tags, since this will give other unwanted data from the page.

Any other way to get the desired output?

TIA.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: Noted. will amend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get bios about every member found on the page you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/leadership/managers"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('td > a[href*="/about/"]'):
    link = a["href"]
    if "http" not in link:
        link = "https://www.worldbank.org" + link

    print(link)

    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    for text in s.select(
        ".parbase:has(p):not(:has(.parbase)), #block-icsid-content"
    ):
        print(text.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))

    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/people/d/david-malpass
David R. Malpass, 13 th President of the World Bank Group David R. Malpass was selected as 13 th President of the World Bank Group by its Board of Executive Directors on April 5, 2019.  His five-year term began on April 9. Mr. Malpass previously served as Under Secretary of the Treasury for International Affairs for the United States.  Mr. Malpass represented the United States in international settings, including the G-7 and G-20 Deputy Finance Ministerial, World Bank–IMF Spring and Annual Meetings, and meetings of the Financial Stability Board, the Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development, and the Overseas Private Investment Corporation. In 2018, Mr. Malpass advocated for the capital increase for the IBRD and IFC as part of a reform agenda featuring sustainable lending practices, more efficient use of capital, and a focus on raising living standards in poor countries.  He was also instrumental in advancing the Debt Transparency ...

...and so on.
```